# SQL where NOT EQUAL TO isn't working as intended - SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

I have the following query that is working differently when using != (or <>) compared to =.

The example I'm trying this with works as follows.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1
```

returns **100**.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM table1 
WHERE year = '2017/2018' AND SOURCE = 'CSV'
```

returns **30**.

Why then would the below not return a count of **70**?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM table1 
WHERE year != '2017/2018' AND SOURCE != 'CSV'
```

It appears to treat it like an OR instead of AND when updating to != and I'm struggling to figure out why. I have got around the issue by changing my query to use NOT EXISTS with a subselect, but the initial question remains.

Comment: DeMorgan Law. Use `or`. Draw a Venn diagram.

Answer (score 6):

Because there are rows where year is 2017/18 but source is not CSV, or source is CSV but year is not 2017/18. See [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Perhaps what you want is:

```
WHERE NOT (year = '2017/2018' AND SOURCE = 'CSV')
```

Personally I'm not normally a big fan of the `NOT ()` wrapper, but in this case it best describes the semantics you're after. You could also say:

```
WHERE year <> '2017/2018' OR SOURCE <> 'CSV'
---- important difference ^^
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=381aeea355a72a99091b192397a0fba8)

Think about it another way. The parking lot has 10 cars, and we want to find out how many cars are red BMWs (let's call it `x`), and how many cars are NOT red BMWs (which should be `10 - x`):

| Color | Make | Red? | BMW? | Red AND BMW? | Not Red? | Not BMW? | Not Red AND Not BMW? | Not Red OR Not BMW? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Red** | **BMW** | Yes | Yes | Yes | No | No | No | No |
| **Red** | **BMW** | Yes | Yes | Yes | No | No | No | No |
| **Red** | **BMW** | Yes | Yes | Yes | No | No | No | No |
| Silver | **BMW** | No | Yes | No | Yes | No | No | Yes |
| **Red** | Honda | Yes | No | No | No | Yes | No | Yes |
| Purple | Toyota | No | No | No | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Green | Lexus | No | No | No | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Green | Toyota | No | No | No | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Black | Ford | No | No | No | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Orange | Audi | No | No | No | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
|  | **Sum of Yes:** | **4** | **4** | **3** | **6** | **6** | **5** | **7** |

If you count up all the cars that are both red and BMW, you get 3. If you want the inverse of that (the 7 remaining cars), you can't count up all the cars that are both NOT red and NOT BMW. This would skip the silver BMW and the red Honda, giving 5, not 7. You need to count all the cars that are *either* not red *OR* not BMW. Or that are *NOT* both red *AND* BMW.

Comment: Thank you, perhaps it's just my lack of understanding on how != or <> works but I'd assumed it would just do the opposite of what the = does essentially.

Comment: `=` and `!=` (and `<>`) are semantically opposites, but you don't have 1 `=`, @Ghost_21 , so just swapping out the `=` for `!=` on it's own no longer gives you the opposite.

Comment: @Ghost_21 when you have one (and no NULLs), yes, but when you have multiple conditions, flipping the signs doesn't give you the complement.

Comment: Thanks both for the feedback. The logic still seems a little off to me, but at least I now know how to deal with it.

Comment: @Ghost_21 What part doesn't make sense? Think about the BMWs. There are 3 red BMWs (`color = red AND make = BMW`). There's also a silver BMW. Does it meet (`color != red AND make != BMW`)? No. It only meets `color != red`.

Comment: In other words, `how many cars are not red AND are not BMWs` is a different question than `how many cars are not red OR are not BMWs`.

Comment: But the filter I used wasn't how many are not red OR are not BMW, it was not red AND not BMW. To me that should have worked as the inverse of equals red AND equals BMW.

Comment: @Ghost_21 no, it is still not the inverse. And I know the filter *you used* was not "not red OR not BMW," I was saying that if you wanted the inverse of "red AND BMW" you need "not (red AND BMW)." Because "not red AND not BMW" means silver BMWs and red Hondas are not counted.

Comment: @Ghost_21 updated the answer (and [the fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=381aeea355a72a99091b192397a0fba8)) hopefully to make it clearer for you.